# How to make  $.get return a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code in JavaScript and jQuery and I need to fix it:

```
function valid_form() {
val_avail_email=valid_avail_email();

if (val_avail_email!="") {
$("#email_valid").html(val_avail_email);
return false;
}

return true;
}

function valid_avail_email() {
    var error="";

    $.get("valid_avail_email.php",{email:document.reg_form.email_reg.value},function(output) {
        error=output;
    });

    return error;
}
```

So obviously I want the `error` variable to contain the output of the `valid_avail_email.php` and than make the `valid_avail_email()` function return that value.

Here is the code in `valid_avail_email.php`:

```
<?php
include("config.php");

$email=$_GET["email"];

$sql="select email from users";
$sql_query=mysql_query($sql);

if (!$sql_query) {
    echo mysql_error();
}

$res_assoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_query);

foreach ($res_assoc as $field=>$value) {
   if ($value==$email) {
       echo "please use another email this one is taken ";
   }
}

?>
```

Comment: This is an important moment in your javascript career :)

Comment: Sidenote: you fetch ALL email addresses from your database and then loop them to find $email? This is very inefficient.

$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '{$email}'";
// check if there are results

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that the $.get() function initiates an asynchronous ajax call, means, the function returns while the ajax call is still running. You have to inform the GUI from within the ajax callback function, e.g.:

```
$.get("valid_avail_email.php",{email:document.reg_form.email_reg.value},function(output) {
  error=output;
  if (error !== '')
    alert('Sorry, use another email!');
```

});

Comment: thank you for replying but i really need the valid_avail_email() function to return the error value becuase i have another function that is getting the errors and stop the submitting if there is an error

Comment: Well, if you want check the emails on the server-side, you HAVE to wait for the asynchronous return of you ajax call. There is a possibility to initiate a synchronous ajax call, but this is highly not recommended... So call your 2nd function from within the ajax success() callback, and check it first.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to do a foreach loop to check if the email is in db. just do a following query:

```
SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '$email'
```

and check if the result contains any item. this method is faster than enumerating all the emails with "foreach" loop because the db returns 1 or 0 results and not thousands if you have a big db.

your valid_avail_email() is ok.. just check in your JS if the function returns anything, if yes, there alert shows the error:

```
var emailOk = valid_avail_email("blabla@email.com");
if(emailOk != ""){
//the following alert will show the error from php, it can show mysql_error() or "please use another email.." message
alert(emailOk);
//do stuff to abort the script
}
```

Comment: i added the whole code you can see why i need the valid_avail_email() function to return an error value.